# the function getrandom() only returning -1

Tags: c++, linux

I am attempting to get random numbers out of the getrandom() function however attempting to use it only returns -1 the code i am using below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <sys/random.h>
int main(){
    void* d = NULL;
    ssize_t size = 10;
    ssize_t p = getrandom(d, size, GRND_RANDOM);
    std::cout << p << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: you haven't allocated anything for the `d` buffer

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html#RETURN_VALUE

Comment: Interesting that it actually handles the case of unallocated memory; returns `-1` and sets `errno` to `EFAULT` in that case, which the OP would likely see if they bothered to check `errno`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getrandom` returns the number of bytes written.  The first argument is the pointer to a byte buffer (to be filled with random bytes), the second argument is the number of random bytes that you want to be written to the buffer.

Your return value (`p`) being `-1` means that there was an error when writing the random bytes to the buffer.  This error in your case is because you are passing in `NULL` as the pointer to the buffer to be filled.

Try this instead:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <sys/random.h>
int main(){
  unsigned char random_bytes[2]; // buffer where getrandom will store the random bytes
  ssize_t size = 2;
  ssize_t p = getrandom((void*) &random_bytes[0], size, GRND_RANDOM);
  std::cout << "First random value: " << random_bytes[0] << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Second random value: " << random_bytes[1] << std::endl;
}
```

source:
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrandom.2.html